# How to invoke TSQL statement with params?

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

How can I use params in tsql or alternatively re-use the values in a merge statement without having to pass the values multiple times?  What am I doing wrong?

Running TSQL with params throws exception below

> The variable name '@p1' has already been declared. Variable names must
> be unique within a query batch or stored procedure."

Using table def as example:

```
dbo.Test
(
[key]      VarChar(50),
[value]    VarChar(50)
)
```

Sample Java code:

```
try (PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement("DECLARE @p1 VarChar(50) DECLARE @p2 VarChar(50) SET @p1 = ? SET @p2 = ? INSERT dbo.Test ([key], [value]) values(@p1, @p2)"))
{
    s.setString(1,"Hello");
    s.setString(2,"World");
    s.execute();
}
```

Also tried below with same results

```
DECLARE @p1 VarChar(50) = ?
DECLARE @p2 VarChar(50) = ?
```

**EDIT:**
The code above is just a sample, I need/want to use param so I don't have to set the same values multiple times for use in a [Merge Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

A merge statement for dbo.Test would look like this:

```
DECLARE @key    VarChar(50)
DECLARE @val    VarChar(50)

MERGE dbo.Test t
USING (SELECT @key [k]) s
    ON t.[key] = s.k
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET t.[value] = @val
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([key], [value])
    VALUES (@key, @val);
```

I'd rather not have to set the same value again and again

Comment: Perhaps named parameters would help. [Named Parameters in JDBC Queries](https://dzone.com/articles/parameterized-jdbc-queries-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use TSQL variables, just insert the values directly.

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.Test ([key], [value]) VALUES (?, ?)";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, "Hello");
    stmt.setString(2, "World");
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

---

**UPDATE** for question edit using `MERGE`:

> The code above is just a sample, I need/want to use param so I don't have to set the same values multiple times for use in a [Merge Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

If you follow the example shown in that link, you'll see that the variables are only used once each, so there is no reason to require variables at all when executed from Java.

[Example A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-merge-to-do-insert-and-update-operations-on-a-table-in-a-single-statement) from link:

> ```sql
> MERGE Production.UnitMeasure AS target  
> USING (SELECT @UnitMeasureCode, @Name) AS source (UnitMeasureCode, Name)  
> ON (target.UnitMeasureCode = source.UnitMeasureCode)  
> WHEN MATCHED THEN
>     UPDATE SET Name = source.Name  
> WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  
>     INSERT (UnitMeasureCode, Name)  
>     VALUES (source.UnitMeasureCode, source.Name)  
> OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.* INTO #MyTempTable;
> ```

As applied to the question's statement:

```java
String sql = "MERGE dbo.Test AS t" +
            " USING (SELECT ?, ?) AS s (k, v)" +
               " ON t.[key] = s.k" +
             " WHEN MATCHED THEN" +
                 " UPDATE SET [value] = s.v" +
             " WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN" +
                 " INSERT ([key], [value])" +
                 " VALUES (s.k, s.v)";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, "Hello"); // s.k
    stmt.setString(2, "World"); // s.v
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'd do that in a hearbeat if I didn't have to reuse the values.  I need to use the params to not repeat setting the same values over and over.  See update

Comment: of course!  why didn't I think of using an alias....smh   :)

thank you very much, that should do the trick